# Losing accuracy for large integers (pow?)

Tags: c++

I am trying to minimise an energy function to find solutions to Tammes's Problem. My code works by using a gradient flow method and I can change the value of my variable t (the power the energy function is taken to) to estimate solutions.

Tammes's Problem is the result when t tends to infinity and obviously I therefore want t to be as large as possible.

The problem is my as I increase t my solutions (the energy calculated) lose accuracy.

I believe this is to do with the pow() function and the fact that it is calculating with such large integers.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

int main()
{

  int a,b,c,d,f,i,j,k,m,n,s,t,Success,Fails;
  double p,theta,phi,Time,Averagetime,Energy,energy,Distance,Length,DotProdForce,
         Forcemagnitude,ForceMagnitude[201],Force[201][4],E[1000001],En[501],Epsilon[4],Ep,
         x[201][4],new_x[201][4],y[201][4],A[201],alpha[201][201],degree,bestalpha[501];

  clock_t t1,t2;
  t1=clock();

t=1;

while(t<1001){

n=2;

while(n<51){

cout << "N=" << n << "\n";

  b=1;
  Time=0.0;

  while(b<101){

    clock_t t3,t4;
    t3=clock();

    if(n>200){
      cout << n << " is too many points for me :-( \n";
      exit(0);
    }

    srand((unsigned)time(0));  

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
      x[i][1]=((rand()*1.0)/(1.0*RAND_MAX)-0.5)*2.0;
      x[i][2]=((rand()*1.0)/(1.0*RAND_MAX)-0.5)*2.0;
      x[i][3]=((rand()*1.0)/(1.0*RAND_MAX)-0.5)*2.0;

      Length=sqrt(pow(x[i][1],2)+pow(x[i][2],2)+pow(x[i][3],2));

      for (k=1;k<=3;k++){
        x[i][k]=x[i][k]/Length;
      }
    }

    Energy=0.0;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
        Distance=sqrt(pow(x[i][1]-x[j][1],2)+pow(x[i][2]-x[j][2],2)
                    +pow(x[i][3]-x[j][3],2));

        Energy=Energy+1.0/pow(Distance,t);
      }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      y[i][1]=x[i][1];
      y[i][2]=x[i][2];
      y[i][3]=x[i][3];
    }

    m=100;

    if (m>100){
      cout << "The m="<< m << " loop is inefficient...lessen m \n";
      exit(0);
    }

    a=1;

    while(a<m){

      for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
        x[i][1]=((rand()*1.0)/(1.0*RAND_MAX)-0.5)*2.0;
        x[i][2]=((rand()*1.0)/(1.0*RAND_MAX)-0.5)*2.0;
        x[i][3]=((rand()*1.0)/(1.0*RAND_MAX)-0.5)*2.0;

        Length=sqrt(pow(x[i][1],2)+pow(x[i][2],2)+pow(x[i][3],2));

        for (k=1;k<=3;k++){
          x[i][k]=x[i][k]/Length;
        }
      }

      energy=0.0;

      for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
          Distance=sqrt(pow(x[i][1]-x[j][1],2)+pow(x[i][2]-x[j][2],2)
                        +pow(x[i][3]-x[j][3],2));

          energy=energy+1.0/pow(Distance,t);
        }
      }

      if(energy<Energy)
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
          for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            Energy=energy;
            y[i][j]=x[i][j];
          }
        }
      else
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
          for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            energy=Energy;
            x[i][j]=y[i][j];
          }
        }

      a=a+1;
    }

    /* 
    ostringstream String1;
    String1 << "BestTamrandompoints_" << t << "_" << n;  //add number

    ofstream File1 (String1.str().c_str());
    File1 << "Energy=" << Energy << "\n";
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      File1 << x[i][1] << " " <<   x[i][2] << " " << x[i][3] << "\n";
    }
    File1.close(); 
    */

    E[0]=Energy;

    a=1;
    s=0;
    f=0;
    Forcemagnitude=1.0;

    if(n>80 && t<11)
      p=0.005;
    else if(n>60 && t<11)
      p=0.01;
    else if(n>40 && t<11)
      p=0.02;
    else if(n>25 && t<11)
      p=0.05;
    else if(n>40 && t>11)
      p=0.002;
    else if(n>30 && t>11)
      p=0.005;
    else if(n>20 && t>11)
      p=0.01;
    else if(n>5 && t>11)
      p=0.025;
    else
      p=0.05;

    while(Forcemagnitude>0.000001 && a<1000001){

      for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ 
        Force[i][1]=0.0; 
        Force[i][2]=0.0; 
        Force[i][3]=0.0; 
      } 

      for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ 
        for(j=1;j<i;j++){

          Distance=sqrt(pow(x[i][1]-x[j][1],2)+pow(x[i][2]-x[j][2],2)
                        +pow(x[i][3]-x[j][3],2));

          Force[i][1]=Force[i][1]+((x[i][1]-x[j][1])/(pow((Distance),3))); 
          Force[i][2]=Force[i][2]+((x[i][2]-x[j][2])/(pow((Distance),3))); 
          Force[i][3]=Force[i][3]+((x[i][3]-x[j][3])/(pow((Distance),3))); 
        } 

        for (j=i+1;j<=n;j++){ 

          Distance=sqrt(pow(x[i][1]-x[j][1],2)+pow(x[i][2]-x[j][2],2)
                        +pow(x[i][3]-x[j][3],2));

          Force[i][1]=Force[i][1]+((x[i][1]-x[j][1])/(pow((Distance),3))); 
          Force[i][2]=Force[i][2]+((x[i][2]-x[j][2])/(pow((Distance),3))); 
          Force[i][3]=Force[i][3]+((x[i][3]-x[j][3])/(pow((Distance),3)));
        }
      }

      for(i=1;i<=n;i++){

        DotProdForce=Force[i][1]*x[i][1]+Force[i][2]*x[i][2]+Force[i][3]*x[i][3];

        y[i][1]=x[i][1];
        y[i][2]=x[i][2];
        y[i][3]=x[i][3];

        Force[i][1]=Force[i][1]-DotProdForce*y[i][1];
        Force[i][2]=Force[i][2]-DotProdForce*y[i][2];
        Force[i][3]=Force[i][3]-DotProdForce*y[i][3];

        x[i][1] = y[i][1]+p*(Force[i][1]);
        x[i][2] = y[i][2]+p*(Force[i][2]);
        x[i][3] = y[i][3]+p*(Force[i][3]);

        Length=sqrt(pow(x[i][1],2)+pow(x[i][2],2)+pow(x[i][3],2));

        for (j=1;j<=3;j++){
          x[i][j]=x[i][j]/Length;
        }
      }

      energy=0.0;

      for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++){

          Distance=sqrt(pow(x[i][1]-x[j][1],2)+pow(x[i][2]-x[j][2],2)
                        +pow(x[i][3]-x[j][3],2));
          energy=energy+1.0/pow(Distance,t);
        }
      }

      E[a]=energy;

      for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        ForceMagnitude[i]=pow((pow(Force[i][1],2)+pow(Force[i][2],2)
                               +pow(Force[i][3],2)),0.5);
      }

      cout << "E[" << a << "]=" << E[a] << "\n";

      cout << fixed << setprecision(40) << "Energy=" << Energy << " energy=" << energy << "\n";

      if (energy<Energy)
        Energy=energy,s=s+1;
      else
        energy=Energy,f=f+1,p=(9.5*p)/10;

      for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++){
        if(ForceMagnitude[i]<ForceMagnitude[i+1])
          ForceMagnitude[i]=ForceMagnitude[i+1];
        else
          ForceMagnitude[i+1]=ForceMagnitude[i];
      }

      Ep=sqrt(pow(E[a]-E[a-1],2));

      if (Ep<0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001){
        ForceMagnitude[n]=0.000001;
        cout << "BROKEN \n";
      }
      else
        ForceMagnitude[n]=ForceMagnitude[n];

      Forcemagnitude=ForceMagnitude[n];

      cout << fixed << setprecision(60) << "FM=" << Forcemagnitude << "\n";
      cout << "Energy=" << Energy << "\n";

      a=a+1;
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
        Distance=sqrt(pow(x[i][1]-x[j][1],2)+pow(x[i][2]-x[j][2],2)
                        +pow(x[i][3]-x[j][3],2));

        degree=(180/PI);

        alpha[i][j]=degree*acos((2.0-pow(Distance,2))/2.0);
      }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
        cout << "alpha[" << i << "][" << j << "]=" << alpha[i][j] << "\n";
      }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++){
      for(j=i+1;j<=n-1;j++){
        if(alpha[i][j]>alpha[i][j+1])
          alpha[i][j]=alpha[i][j+1];
        else
          alpha[i][j+1]=alpha[i][j];
      }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
        cout << "alpha[" << i << "][" << j << "]=" << alpha[i][j] << "\n";
      }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n-2;i++){
      if(alpha[i][n]>alpha[i+1][n])
        alpha[i][n]=alpha[i+1][n];
      else
        alpha[i+1][n]=alpha[i][n];
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
        cout << "alpha[" << i << "][" << j << "]=" << alpha[i][j] << "\n";
      }
    }

    bestalpha[b]=alpha[n-1][n];

    En[b]=Energy;

    b=b+1;

    t4=clock();
    float diff ((float)t4-(float)t3);
    float seconds = diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    Time = Time + seconds;

  }

  Averagetime = Time/(b-1);

  cout << fixed << setprecision (4) << "Average Time: " << Averagetime << "(s) \n";
  cout << fixed << setprecision(10) << "Energy=" << Energy << "\n";
  cout << "s=" << s << " f=" << f << "\n";

  Success=Success+s;
  Fails=Fails+f;

  cout << "Successes=" << Success << " Failures=" << Fails << "\n";
  cout << setprecision(5) << "Success Rate=" << ((Success*1.0)/((Success*1.0)+(Fails*1.0)))*100.0 << "\n";

  t2=clock();
    float diff ((float)t2-(float)t1);
    float seconds = diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
      y[i][j]=x[i][j];
    }
  }

  a=1;
  d=0;
  c=0;

  while(a<2){

  theta=x[a][2]/x[a][3];
  theta=d*PI+atan(theta);

  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    new_x[i][1]=x[i][1];
    new_x[i][2]=x[i][2]*cos(theta)-x[i][3]*sin(theta);
    new_x[i][3]=x[i][2]*sin(theta)+x[i][3]*cos(theta);
  }

  phi=new_x[a][1]/new_x[a][3];
  phi=c*PI+atan(phi);

  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    x[i][1]=new_x[i][1]*cos(phi)-new_x[i][3]*sin(phi);
    x[i][2]=new_x[i][2];
    x[i][3]=new_x[i][1]*sin(phi)+new_x[i][3]*cos(phi);
  }

  Epsilon[1]=sqrt(pow((x[a][1]),2));  
  Epsilon[2]=sqrt(pow((x[a][2]),2));
  Epsilon[3]=sqrt(pow((x[a][3]-1.0),2));  

  cout << "x[" << a << "][1]=" << x[a][1] << " x[" << a << "][2]=" << x[a][2] << " x[" << a << "][3]=" << x[a][3] << "\n";  

   if(Epsilon[1]<0.00001 && Epsilon[2]<0.00001 && Epsilon[3]<0.00001)
    a=a+1;
  else if(d==0 && c==0)
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
        x[i][j]=y[i][j];
        c=1;
      }
    }
  else if(d==0 && c==1)
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
        x[i][j]=y[i][j];
        d=1;
        c=0;
      }
    }
  else if(d==1 && c==0)
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
        x[i][j]=y[i][j];
        c=1;
      }
    }
  else if(d==1 && c==1)
    break;

  }

  cout << "a=" << a << " d=" << d << " c=" << c << "\n";

  ostringstream String2;
  String2 << "TamPoints_" << t << "_" << n;  //add number

  ofstream File2 (String2.str().c_str());
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    File2 << x[i][1] << " " <<   x[i][2] << " " << x[i][3] << "\n";
  }
  File2.close(); 

  ostringstream String3;
  String3 << "TamEnergies_" << t << "_" << n;  //add number

  ofstream File3 (String3.str().c_str());
  for(i=1;i<a;i++){
    File3 << fixed << setprecision (10) << E[i] << "\n";
  }
  File3.close(); 

  ofstream File4 ("mypoints");
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    File4 << x[i][1] << " " <<   x[i][2] << " " << x[i][3] << "\n";
  }
  File4.close(); 

  ostringstream String4;
  String4 << "TamInfo_" << t << "_" << n;  //add number

  ofstream File5 (String4.str().c_str());
  File5 << "Iterations=" << a-1 << "\n";
  File5 << "Successes=" << s << " Failures=" << f << "\n";
  File5 << fixed << setprecision(20) << "Energy=" << Energy << "\n";
  File5 << fixed << setprecision(5) << "Total run time: " << seconds << "(s) \n";
  File5 << fixed << setprecision(5) << "Average run time: " << Averagetime << "(s) \n";
  File5.close(); 

  ostringstream String5;
  String5 << "Tam%Energies_" << t << "_" << n;  //add number

  ofstream File6 (String5.str().c_str());
  for(i=1;i<b;i++){
    File6 << fixed << setprecision(20) << En[i] << "\n";
  }
  File6.close();

  ostringstream String6;
  String6 << "TamAngles_" << t << "_" << n << ".2";  //add number

  ofstream File7 (String6.str().c_str());
  for(i=1;i<b;i++){
      File7 << fixed << setprecision(15) << bestalpha[i] << "\n";
  }
  File7.close();

  cout << fixed << setprecision(5) << "Run time: " << seconds << "(s)" << "\n";

  n=n+1;
  }

    if(t==1)
    t=2;
    else if(t==2)
    t=5;
    else if(t==5)
    t=10;
    else if(t==10)
    t=25;
    else if(t==25)
    t=50;
    else if(t==50)
    t=100;  
    else if(t==100)
    t=250;
    else if(t==250)
    t=500;
    else if(t==500)
    t=1000;
    else
    t=t+1;
}

  return 0;

}
```

Note: I appreciate my code is horrendously crude, however my dissertation is in soon and therefore I can't spend time making it pretty, I just need it to work. I apologise in advance for the lack of functions, I am new to coding of any kind and didn't realise these were to be used until I felt it would be counter productive to spend all my time neatening. My issue I am sure is with the energy calculations which are: 1/pow(Distance,t), and so as t increases they lose accuracy. The code works fine for small t (at least up to 100) however for t=250 the code starts to fail on accuracy.

Is there any way to fix this quickly?? I have heard of the bignum library but I don't know anything about it and shall be reading up on it tonight. Thanks to all in advance, A.

Comment: I know you're not asking about this. But that declaration of things 25 things as double in main is very close to eating out all your stack space.

Comment: @carlosdc: it's a FORTRAN style as far as I can tell (given 1 indexing as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track -- you need arbitrary precision integers.  I've used [the GMP library](http://gmplib.org/) in the past, but that was a long time ago...  Good luck!

Comment: So last night I got the GMP library and managed to get it working, now I need to know how to use it and rewrite my code a little. Does anyone know off the bat what I should be altering? Just t, or energy, Energy and Distance as well? or the whole lot?

Comment: Note: For those who chance across this later I compiled using `$ g++ -o program "filename.cc" -lgmpxx -lgmp -I /folder/where/header/is -L /folder/where/library/is` and put #include <gmpxx.h> into my scope. They will all usually be in the folder you originally unzip. If you can't find it, the library is literally called libgmpxx.dylib and gmpxx.4.dylib and header is called gmpxx.h

Comment: I am really confused as to how to use GMP, I have set up another question as I think it should be one of its own accord, but I was wondering if you have any pointers or comments on what I have done there? Thanks, A. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741101/using-gmp-library-to-alter-my-code-what-to-change

Comment: You should be replacing your builtin types with GMP types, and use the GMP routines for calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make t arbitrarily large, you need a bignum library.

For a quick fix that may work depending on how large you need t to be, try declaring your numbers as `unsigned long long` (if they will always be positive) or a `long long` instead of `int` (learn more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Do you mean just t, or Distance as well or all that could cause loss of accuracy??

Comment: To start, I would try doing it to all variables that you've currently declared as an int. Then if it works you can, if you'd like, take the time to figure out exactly which ones need to be change and which ones can remain as ints. And if it doesn't work then you didn't waste as much time trying.

Comment: Afraid this didn't work, thnks for the hint though, something to look into when I have more time.