# Program working for small sized arrays but not large sized

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, insert

The problem:

> You are given a large integer represented as an integer array digits, where each digits[i] is the ith digit of the integer. The digits are ordered from most significant to least significant in left-to-right order. The large integer does not contain any leading 0's.
>
> Increment the large integer by one and return the resulting array of digits."

This is what went wrong

Input:

```
[6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]
```

Output:

```
[6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,4,0,9]
```

Expected:

```
[6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,4]
```

It worked for `[1,2,3]`.

I tried to write the number in the form of base 10.For example writing 423 as: `(4*10^2 + 2*10^1 + 3*10^0)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> plusOne(vector<int>& digits) {
        long long n = digits.size();
        long long s = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
          s += digits[i]*(pow(10,(n-(i+1)))); 
        }
        s+=1;
        vector<int> ndig;
        while (s){
            ndig.insert(ndig.begin(),s%10);
            s/=10;
        }
        return ndig;
    }
};
```

Comment: Of course this will fail for lange numbers because `math.pow` is working with doubles and doubles only have about 15-17 digits of precision. Thus when you do `math.pow(10, 18) * 6) you are losing information. Read also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Why do you even need `math.pow`? Just do it, like you would manually increment a number by 1. You don't deal with powers when you do this on paper, do you? Ie (1) increment the last element of your array by 1.  (2) If it's in the range of `1-9` after the increment you are done. (3) If it's not (ie it's 10) set it to `0` and do steps 1-3 on the previous element in the array. Do this until the incremented element is in the range of `1-9`. If the very first element of this array becomes 10, set it to `0` and insert a new element with `1` in the beginning of the array.

Comment: This is an integer-based problem.  Do not use `pow` or any other floating point function to solve integer-based problems.

Answer (score 2):

The issue when the vector becomes greater is that it is possible that long long will not be able to store the value.

Now, with the example, [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3] should be within the range. However, a single item more and long long will not be enough to store the value. ([type value ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)).

The issue occurs due to pow, since it operates with floating points representation, which would produce issues when dealing with large integers. This is explained better here: [losing accuracy for large integers pow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735208/losing-accuracy-for-large-integers-pow)

Now, I suggest using an inverse iterator since it will allow you to execute your operation (adding one) in place without storing the value in a separate variable, bypassing the storage issue of long long type and the issue with pow for large integer operations.

Using a reverse iterator, you bypass the size issue.

```
for(auto it = digits.rbegin(); it != digits.rend(); ++it) {
  if (*it < 9) {
    // No need to carry the increment, add 1.
    ++(*it);
    return digits;
  }
  // Convert 9 to 0 and carry the one to the next iteration.
  *it = 0;
}

// If the for loop did not return, all digits' items were 9's
// Add a 1 to the beginning of the vector.
digits.insert(digits.begin(), 1)
return digits;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are adding a floating point number to an integer. Compiling with the `-Wall` option in clang++ gives the following warning:

```
warning: implicit conversion turns floating-point number into integer: 'typename std::__enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<int>::value && std::is_arithmetic<long long>::value, std::__promote<int, long long>>::type' (aka 'double') to 'long long' [-Wfloat-conversion]
   11 |       s += digits[i]*(pow(10,(n-(i+1)))); 
      |       ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

You could try rounding the value, but that would still give wrong results at larger values because of floating-point precision.

Instead, try operating directly on the vector without converting it into `int`

```cpp
void plusOne(vector<int>& v) {
    // Add one to the last digit of the vector
    v[v.size() - 1]++;

    // For each element of the vector, see if they are greater than 10
    for (int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        // If so, carry
        if (v[i] >= 10 && i != 0) {
            v[i] -= 10;
            v[i - 1]++;
            continue;
        }

        // If the first digit carries, add one by inserting an element
        if (v[i] >= 10 && i == 0) {
            v[i] -= 10;
            v.insert(v.begin(), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for [@derpirschir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher) for pointing out the mistakes (my bad!). They have been fixed

Comment: Your first "fix" still will give you wrong results if the numbers get big enough, because `double` just doesn't have enough precision to hold the exact value of a number with more then about 17 digits. Your second approach is just plain wrong, because it doesn't handle overflows. Ie try, what happens when you apply this to a  vector like `[1,2,9]` ...